# javascript regex for tab followed by a space

Tags: javascript, regex, tabs

In Javascript what would be the regex for a tab followed by a space (EXACTLY THAT).

I know it's something like:

```
var c = dataString.replace(/\t\s/g,'<br />');
```

But this is finding tabs or spaces globally, not a tab followed by a space as an exact match.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would be `/\t /`

`\s` also matches other whitespace characters, so you need a literal space character.